# why I still get deleted documents when getting data using listener from Firestore in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I trying to make an event app. and I  add a new field in my events documents. I try to add "venue" field for my event documents

so before I run the app, I delete all the available data on my Firestore database. But when I retrieve my data back to the app, it is said that the "venue" is nil, it seems that the "venue" field is not exist, even though in fact, the "venue" field exist on my firestore database.

I suspect my app still retrieve my deleted documents. here is why

here is the code I use :

```
enum FirestoreCollectionReference {
    case users
    case events
    case cities
    case APIKey

    private var path : String {
        switch self {
        case .users : return "users"
        case .events : return "events"
        case .cities : return "cities"
        case .APIKey : return "secretAPIKeyKM"
        }
    }

    func reference () -> CollectionReference {
        return Firestore.firestore().collection(path)
    }
}


FirestoreCollectionReference.events.reference()
                .whereField("city", isEqualTo: selectedCity)
                .whereField("eventType", isEqualTo: selectedEventType)
                .whereField("coordinate", isGreaterThan: lesserGeopoint)
                .whereField("coordinate", isLessThan: greaterGeopoint)
                .order(by: "coordinate")
                .order(by: "dateTimeStart", descending: true)
                .limit(to: 20)
                .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

                    if let error = error {
                        completion(nil,eventListener)
                        print("Error when observing events document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Successfully get events data from Firestore by Listener")

                        guard let documentsSnapshot = snapshot else {
                            completion(nil, eventListener)
                            return
                        }


                        let eventDocuments = documentsSnapshot.documents

                        print("the number of documents: \(eventDocuments.count)")


                        var eventsArray = [EventKM]()

                        for document in eventDocuments {
                            let eventDictionary = document.data()
                            let theEvent = EventKM(dictionary: eventDictionary)
                            eventsArray.append(theEvent)
                        }

                        completion(eventsArray,eventListener)

                    }

            }



        }
```

I try to print the number of documents, and it shows that I have 8 documents from this query, in fact, it should be only one document available in my database.

I try to delete the composite indexes from firebase console, but usually, after I delete the composite indexes, It will give an error + a link to generate the composite indexes in my debugging area on my Xcode, but after I delete the composite indexes, I don't get the error + link to generate the indexes, and give 8 documents (it should be one document only)

it seems the data is cached on my iOS app. isn't it? or is this a bug since Firestore is still in Beta version? I need to understand why and how to solve this issue so I can understand firebase better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the data is indeed cached on your device, the snapshot listener should fire twice: the first time with the (outdated) data from the cache, the second time with the (updated) data from the server. If that second time doesn't happen, it is most likely that the client can't connect to the Firestore servers.

Comment: yes, the cached data that make my app crash. can I programatically remove/delete the cache ? I mean totally remove it, not using .isPersistenceEnabled = false?

Comment: There is no API to remove the cached data. But after you successfully (so without a crash) listen for the updated data once, the cache should be updated. If that doesn't work, delete the app and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

**FireBase has cached in device** so if user stay in outside of internet,
But still can use Firebase.

**So You just remove your app in your simulator.**

In my case, It fixed.

[image]